# Thermodynamics of thermometer

Tags: thermal-radiation, density

Mercury is used in thermometers because it increases in length significantly due to rise in temperature, However, mercury has high density relative to water, which means more inter-molecular forces which makes it harder to expand than water. Then,why is mercury preferred to water in a thermometer?

Comment: Your claims are incorrect, as R Millikan points out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The density of mercury (13.534 g/cm^3) does not imply high intermolecular forces.  It simply reflects that the mercury atom is much more massive than a water molecule.  The atomic weight of mercury is 200.6, while the molecular weight of water is about 18, so mercury atoms take up $\frac {200.6} {18\cdot 13.534}=0.823$ as much volume as a water molecule.  This doesn't say anything about the forces between the atoms.

Probably the worst thing about water for a thermometer (assuming you keep it from freezing) is that the expansion is not linear.  Water hits a maximum density at 4C, so contracts as it drops in temperature from 0 to 4.  Above 4C, it expands quite slowly for a while, then more quickly as it heats up.  A plot of the volume of water as a function of temperature is below.  It makes thermometers much easier if the curve is linear, which this is not.  Over a small range, it is close to linear.  It would work well for medical thermometers with a range of $35-42 C$, say

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't design thermometers and don't know exactly what the engineering tradeoffs are, but here are some advantages of mercury over water that pop to mind:

Mercury doesn't turn to a solid and expand at 0°C.

Mercury is not a clear liquid, which makes seeing it in a clear glass tube a lot easier.

Mercury has much lower vapor pressure than water, so won't evaporate and condense at other parts of the tube.

Mercury is a lot more linear in expansion as a function of temperature than water.  Water isn't even monotonic a few degrees above freezing.  Non-monotonicity is a obvious show stopper for a thermometer material.